# Turn multiple arrays into JSON

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to make a JSON object out of multiple Array in PHP.

```
$a = array("Wis","Dex","Cha" );
$b = array(1,2,2);
$c = array("Perception","Stealth","Intimidation");
$d = array(8,5,1);
```

and I'm trying to get a bunch of JSON out of it such as this:

```
{ $c[0]:$d[0], "Stat":$a[0], "Multiplier:$b[0] };
```

and to get all those JSON and turn them in a string. But I've been trying to understand how json_encode works, but I cannot figure it out. I am hoping someone will be able to explain to me how to manipulate these values to turn them in JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manually create the desired array using a for loop, then use `json_encode` on it. You have to be sure that the four arrays are the same size though.

```
$n = count($a);
$combined = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $entry = array();
    $entry[$c[$i]] = $d[$i];
    $entry["Stat"] = $a[$i];
    $entry["Multiplier"] = $b[$i];

    $combined[$i] = $entry;
}
$json = json_encode(combined);
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked. Just a note, in your $combined[i], you forgot the $ of the $i ;-)

Answer (score 0):

How do you want the data to come out?  As a JSON array of JSON object strings, or each string individually?

```
<?php

$a = array("Wis","Dex","Cha" );
$b = array(1,2,2);
$c = array("Perception","Stealth","Intimidation");
$d = array(8,5,1);

$data[$c[0]]=$d[0];
$data["Stat"]=$a[0];
$data["Multiplier"]=$b[0];

print(json_encode($data));

?>
```

Will give you something like

```
{"Perception":8,"Stat":"Wis","Multiplier":1}
```

If you want an array of those, then a few changes:

```
<?php

$a = array("Wis","Dex","Cha" );
$b = array(1,2,2);
$c = array("Perception","Stealth","Intimidation");
$d = array(8,5,1);

for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++){
   $data[$i][$c[$i]]=$d[$i];
   $data[$i]["Stat"]=$a[$i];
   $data[$i]["Multiplier"]=$b[$i];
}

print(json_encode($data));

?>
```

Which will give you something like

```
[{"Perception":8,"Stat":"Wis","Multiplier":1},
{"Stealth":5,"Stat":"Dex","Multiplier":2},
{"Intimidation":1,"Stat":"Cha","Multiplier":2}]
```